# Proof of $\|A\|_2\le\sqrt{n}.\|A\|_1$, $A\in\Bbb{R}^{m\times n}$

Tags: normed-spaces

Knowing that $\|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_2\le \|x\|_1 \le \sqrt{n}.\|x\|_2\le n.\|x\|_\infty$. How can I demonstrate that $\|A\|_2\le\sqrt{n}.\|A\|_1$, $A\in\Bbb{R}^{m\times n}$?

The entire expression was $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\|A\|_1\le\|A\|_2\le\sqrt{n}.\|A\|_1$. For the first part, I wrote $$\|A.x\|_2\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\|A.x\|_1$$"$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|x\|_1 \le \|x\|_2$, for all $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$" $$ \max_{||x||_2=1}||A.x||_2 \ge\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}.\max_{||x||_1=1}||A.x||_1 \Rightarrow \|A\|_2\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}.\|A\|_1$$
 But I don't know how to do for the second part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\| Ax \|_2 \leq \| Ax \|_1 \leq \| A \|_1 \| x \|_1
\leq \| A \|_1 ( \sqrt{n} \| x \|_2 )
$$
yields, for $x \neq 0$,
$$
\frac { \| Ax \|_2 }{ \| x \|_2}
\leq \sqrt{n} \| A \|_1
$$
Now use the fact that the max is the smallest upper bound.

Comment: But is $||A||_2=\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{||A.x||_2}{||x||_2}\le \frac{||A.x||_2}{||x||_2}$ correct?

Comment: No. You write
$$
\frac{ \| Ax \|_2 }{ \| x \|_2 } \leq \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{ \| Ax \|_2 }{ \| x \|_2 } = \| A \|_2
$$
and 
$$
\frac{ \| Ax \|_2 }{ \| x \|_2 } \leq \sqrt{ n } \| A \|_1
$$
Then you compare the two upper bounds $\| A \|_2$ and $\sqrt{n} \| A \|_1$. By definition of the max, $\| A \|_2$ is the smallest of the two upper bounds.